# Prolog - Constraint Library - Variable Scope

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm working on trying to solve an LSAT logic problem with Prolog. I'm trying to get Prolog to tell me whether possible values for actors in a line are valid.

I wrote the following:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

actor("Jeff",A) :-
        A #>= 0,
        A #<5.
actor("Rich",C) :-
        C #>= 0,
        C #<5,
        actor("Jeff",A),
        A #< C.
```

When I query:

```
?- actor("Rich",0).
false.
```

Which is right since Jeff is < than Rich and Jeff is => 0 so Rich cannot be 0.

But, when I query:

```
?- actor("Jeff",1), actor("Rich",1).
true
```

I also get true, which is impossible because Rich > Jeff.

I feel the problem is because of something going on with my variable. I don't understand how

```
actor("Jeff",A),
A #< C.
```

is evaluating. It seems to me that actor("Jeff",A) should be set to actor("Jeff",1) and then 1 #< 1 should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables *within* a clause or **local** to that clause.

In your case, to understand the issue, consider first the following query:

```
?- actor("Rich", C),
   C = 1.
C = 1.
```

This does not tell us a lot, so we apply the following purely algebraic reasoning: For the goal `actor("Rich", C)`, we substitute the **body** of the single matching clause:

```
?- C #>= 0,
   C #< 5,
   actor("Jeff",A),
   A #< C,
   C = 1.
```

The answer is:

```
C = 1,
A = 0.
```

This shows that when `C` is 1, then `A` is `0`. However, on the toplevel, you did not see this because this variable only occurs *within* the clause for "Rich". Making this explicit shows that there is a *solution* that satisfies the constraint within that clause, but it is not linked to the variable we want.

There are several ways out. One of them is to make `A` available as an *argument* so that you can explicitly refer to it from the toplevel. In general, to link the relevant entities together, you will have to introduce arguments for *each* of your clauses, so that you can refer to the variables you need to reason about, instead of introducing new ones within each clause.

For example, in your case, this could look as follows:

```
actor("Jeff", A, _) :-
        A #>= 0,
        A #< 5.

actor("Rich", A, C) :-
        C #>= 0,
        C #< 5,
        actor("Jeff", A, C),
        A #< C.
```

I have used `A` to refer to Jeff, and `C` to refer to Rich.

While we are at at, let us **tidy up the code**, and use the following essentially *equivalent* version:

```
actor(jeff, A, _) :- A in 0..4.
actor(rich, A, C) :- C in 0..4, actor(jeff, A, C), A #< C.
```

Make sure you understand the following answer:

```
?- actor(jeff, 1, C), actor(rich, C, 1).
C = 0.
```

Your original example now yields `false`, exactly as expected:

```
?- actor(rich, 1, 1).
false.
```

Thus, you should be able to solve your task in principle.

However, there is a much **simpler** way to solve all this, which avoids the **reification overload**.

Instead of painstakingly keeping track of connections between names and corresponding variables, let us use the variables **directly** with the intended names. For example, what do you say about this:

```
?- Jeff in 0..4,
   Rich in 0..4,
   Jeff #< Rich.
```

This uses Prolog variables to denote the people, and makes the work a lot simpler. In this representation, your query becomes:

```
?- Jeff in 0..4,
   Rich in 0..4,
   Jeff #< Rich,
   Jeff = 1,
   Rich = 1.
```

And this obviously results in `false`.